# Restrict suggestions in Algolia to postcode

Tags: filtering, algolia

In Algolia Places I want to restrict the suggestions for streets to a specific postcode. I cannot seem to get it to work however. I thought this might be how it's done, but it doesn't work.

```
const optionsStreet = {
    appId: '...',
    apiKey: '...',
    container: document.querySelector('#address'),
    templates: {
        value: function (suggestion) {
            return suggestion.name;
        }
    }
};

const configStreet = {
    language: 'de', // Receives results in German
    postcodes: ['12345'],
    type: 'address'
};


const placesStreet = places(optionsStreet).configure(configStreet);

placesStreet.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    document.querySelector('#address').value = e.suggestion.name || '';
});
```

Comment: I can't see that anywhere in their options. I'm not sure if it's possible, unfortunately, except manually (restrict to country, then replace `return suggestion.name;` with `return postcodes.indexOf(e.suggestion.postcode) > -1? suggestion.name : '';`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do what you want.
You might want to open a feature request!

In the meantime...

## First option

If that's some data you can get, use the [`insidePolygon`](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#api-options-insidePolygon) option to restrict the searches to the geographical area represented by the postcode(s) you're interested in.
Note that you *can* filter on [multiple disjoint polygons](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/insidePolygon/).

That option is a bit cumbersome to put in place but will give you the best results, as it ensures you'll get only the hits from the area you want.

## Second option

You can also fork the project and fiddle with [that part of the code](https://github.com/algolia/places/blob/master/src/createAutocompleteSource.js#L77-L95):

```js
      .then(content => {
        const hits = content.hits.map((hit, hitIndex) =>
          formatHit({
            formatInputValue: controls.formatInputValue,
            hit,
            hitIndex,
            query,
            rawAnswer: content,
          })
        );

        controls.onHits({
          hits,
          query,
          rawAnswer: content,
        });

        return hits;
      })
```

Filter `content.hits` for the hits that match your postcode only and you'll get your filtered suggestions.

Two recommendations:

1. Increase the `hitsPerPage` setting because you're going to be removing many results from the hits due to your postcode filter:

```js
const placesStreet = places(options).configure({
  ...config,
  computeQueryParams(query) {
    return {...query, hitsPerPage: 100};
  }
});
```

You'll want to fine-tune the `100` depending on what you need.

2. Use the [`arountLatLng`](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#api-options-aroundLatLng) configuration to specify a point within the postcode area you want to target, to maximize the number of hits with the correct postcode.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I will look into that. I think I might be able to get it working with the first approach!

Comment: I didn't get it working yet. However, would it be possible to filter the streets by city instead?